# React Native Webview - How to implement scroll to top button?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

React Native WebView does not seem to support `scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true})` and not sure how to implement the scroll to top button.

This is what my web view looks like in the render.

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: "https://google.com/" }}
  refProps={(webView) => { this.webView.ref = webView; }}
/>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.webView.ref.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0})} /> // How to make this work?
  <Text>Scroll to Top</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This code is not working cause `scrollTo` is not supported in React Native Webview. How to I get around this?

Comment: Hello @Ohsik, did you get any solution, I am also facing the same problem, If there is a solution please let me know?

Answer (score 1):

```
const onPressButton = () => {
    webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(`
      window.scroll({
        top: 0, 
        left: 0, 
        behavior: 'smooth'
      })
    `);
};
```

You can use this code on button press.

Answer (score 0):

Tried following approach works well.

First, post a message to webpage from web-view (put following line of ode in your react-native app)

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.webviewRef.postMessage(JSON.stringify({type: 'scrollToTop'}))} />
  <Text>Scroll to Top</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Then, listen to the message and trigger the scroll event.

```
// JS script on your web page
   onMount(() => {
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        window.addEventListener("message", event => { 
          if (event.data) {
            let parsedEvent = JSON.parse(event.data);
            if (parsedEvent.type === 'scrollToTop') {
              animateScroll.scrollToTop(); 
            }
          }          
        });
   });
// I'm using animateScroll from "svelte-scrollto";
```

Cheers.

Comment: Hello, I am facing this problem, I am trying to your solution, but it's not working?